# Assigning a number value to a date within two dates, specifically the first and last day of a quarter

Tags: sql

I am struggling to write a simple query that will assign a number for the day within 2 dates( beginning and end of quarter.

For example, in Q1'23 Jan 1, 2023 would be day 1 and March 31st, 2023 would be day 90.

I wrote a semi-successful query but my day_count column counts the number of days within the quarter and then just sums revenue for the period. As a result I get:

Structure of query results

[image: 1]

Instead, my goal is to have a `day_count` go from day 1 through day 90-92 (depending on quarter) and then sum the revenue for each day

Structure of Query I'd like to have

[image: 2]

Here is the current query I've written:

```sql
SELECT 
  DATE_TRUNC('quarter', effective_date) AS quarter_start,
  COUNT(DISTINCT effective_date) AS days_count,
  SUM(Revenue) AS Revenue
FROM 
    Table Name
WHERE 
  effective_date BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2023-03-31'
GROUP BY 
  DATE_TRUNC('quarter', effective_date)
ORDER BY Quarter_START ASC;
```

Comment: Hi @connermcnally , Try to add sample data as table instead of pictures

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: I am using Mode Analytics to pull from snowflake